# Trying to set up remote repo and push to it, getting confused

Tags: git, bash

I have a local repo set up on my laptop's hard drive, at `c:\someFolder\.git`.  I want to set up a remote repo on a Windows server at `x:\someOtherFolder` as a backup.  Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. In `x:\someOtherFolder`, opened a git bash session and entered `git clone "c:\someFolder"`.  Got the message `Cloning into 'someFolder'...done.`
2. In `c:\someFolder`, opened a git bash session and entered `git remote add origin "x:\someOtherFolder"`.  Statement executed without response.
3. Made some changes in the local project files and committed them to the local repo with `git commit -am`.
4. From the `c:\someFolder` git bash, entered `git push origin master`.  Response is:

--

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master

remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
```

etc.

I feel like I probably set up the remote incorrectly.  What should I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote server can be only a bare repository (repository without content).
In order to have such a repository you need to create it with the `--bare` flag

```
# create a (bare) remote repository
git init --bare
```

Now you should see the content of the `.git` folder as the file system of that repository and you can start using it.

---

#### Why should a remote repository be a bare repository?

Remote repository does not have any working directory. It simply contains all the content pushed into it from all other local repositories.

---

You don't need a bare repository but this is the convention.

Read all about it in here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

> In order to initially set up any Git server, you have to export an existing repository into a new **bare** repository – **a repository that doesn’t contain a working directory**.
>
> This is generally straightforward to do.
> In order to clone your repository to create a new bare repository, you run the clone command with the **--bare** option.

Comment: No, not necessarily.

Comment: Of course it does not have to be that way. The whole point of git is that its a DVCS. but this is the convention for remote repositories.

Comment: Can I reset it by running `git init --bare` in the remote folder?  Or do I need to do something in the local repo?

Comment: You can do it but its much better to re-clone the repo with the --bare option. since you already have cloned it you will have files in the folder which are the current files in there.

Comment: do it like this: 'git clone --bare <folder> <repo.git>'

Comment: Well, bare repositories have their own purpose, to be hub repositories [for several developers]. This, however, isn't the only goal for them.

Answer (score 1):

No, you did everything right, you've just got into a special situation.

That is, during the push git updates the specified references in the remote repo. In your example this is `master` branch in `someOtherFolder`. It's Ok, but since `master` branch is being checked out currently, then git prevents the push by default, preserving possible changes in the remote directories.

You have three options:

1. Nevertheless, you still can push into `someOtherFolder` if you think it's intended. Perform `git push --force` and don't forget to reset the working tree of `someOtherFolder` with `git reset --hard` issued from within `someOtherFolder`. This, however, is useful only for a few special cases. Suppose, `someOtherFolder` is a "puppet repository" which should contain only changes made in `someFolder` repository. You might find useful to set `receive.denyCurrentBranch = warn` configuration setting in `someOtherFolder`.
2. push your changes into another branch in `someOtherDirectory`: `git push origin master:another_master`. Thus you will create branch `another_master` in `someOtherFolder` only and can do whatever you want with `master` in it then.
3. A more typical solution would be to *fetch* new changes made in `someFolder` into `someOtherFolder`: inside `someOtherFolder` perform `git fetch` and you will get new changes in the remote branch `origin/master`.